# How to open html files having local css links in the phone's browser

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

I have a single HTML and CSS file. The CSS file is linked to the HTML file and everything works fine in the desktop browser but when I want to open it in the phone's browser it does not load the CSS file. they are in the same folder and this is how I tried to reference the CSS file.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css"/>` and I also tried this `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a website running on your computer that you typically access by visiting http://localhost, you can also access this site from your mobile phone as long as both computers are connected to the same network.

[full detail to open the site from mobile](https://howchoo.com/g/mte2zgrhmjf/how-to-access-a-website-running-on-localhost-from-a-mobile-phone)